# Avoid duplicate keys on INSERT INTO/SELECT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, insert-select

I am trying to do an Insert/Select but I am getting a duplicate key error.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.DESTINATION_TABLE
                (
                    DocNumber,
                    TenantId,
                    UserId,
                    OtherField
                )
                SELECT
                    po.DocNumber,
                    po.TenantId,
                    po.CreatedById,
                    po.OtherField
                FROM dbo.SOURCE_TABLE po
                WHERE
                    po.DeletedById IS NULL AND
                    NOT EXISTS(
                        SELECT * FROM dbo.DESTINATION_TABLE poa 
                        WHERE
                           poa.DocNumber = po.DocNumber AND
                           poa.TenantId = po.TenantId
                    )
```

DESTINATION_TABLE has a composite primary key of DocNumber and TenantId. DESTINATION_TABLE is empty at the time of running.

SOURCE_TABLE has a primary key of 'SourceTableId'.

But I keep getting an error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.DESTINATION_TABLE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.DESTINATION_TABLE'. The duplicate key value is (DOC-99, some-tenant).

I have also tried

```
MERGE INTO DESTINATION_TABLE poa
USING (
    SELECT
        x.DocNumber,
        x.TenantId,
        x.CreatedById,
        x.OtherField
    FROM dbo.SOURCE_TABLE x
    WHERE x.DeletedById IS NULL
) po
ON (poa.TenantId = po.TenantId AND poa.DocNumber = po.DocNumber)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (DocNumber, TenantId, UserId, OtherField)
VALUES(po.DocNumber, po.TenantId, po.CreatedById, po.OtherField);
```

But I get the exact same result.

How is this happening? Is it because it is checking for 'NOT EXISTS' before running the insert? How do I fix this?

Comment: *"How is this happening?"* Because you are trying to either insert 2+ rows which have the same values in the columns defined in `PK_dbo.DESTINATION_TABLE` or a row in the table `dbo.DESTINATION_TABLE` already exists with those values and you're trying to `INSERT` another. If your `EXISTS` is working as intended then the former would be the likely candidate.

Comment: Yes, I understand how a PK contraint works. As I mentioned destination table is empty. The source table _does_ have duplicates. But I thought that the `NOT EXISTS` clause would cause that line to not be inserted... Is there a way around this?

Comment: please provide a fiddle to show your problem, source table must have duplicates to cause the problem, so make a count and group by DocNumber, TenantId

Comment: That isn't how SQL works, @sheamus . It works in *sets*. This means that each row isn't inserted one row by (agnonising) row, but in *one* batch. As such the `NOT EXISTS` is only checking if the rows exist in the table prior to the `INSERT`; if you try to insert 2 (or more) rows for the same PK then you try to `INSERT` both and the statement fails.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are saying. So I have to get my source select to be unique somehow... likely taking the first row of a group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the flaw here is your understanding of how SQL works. SQL is a set-based language, so it works with the data in sets. For the above, this means that you define the data you want to `INSERT` with your `SELECT` and then *all* the rows that you define are `INSERT`ed. For your `EXISTS` this means that it only checks against rows that exist in the table *prior* to **any** of the rows being inserted, it does *not* insert each row one at a time and validate the `EXISTS` prior to each row.

Let's take a very *basic* example with a single column table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (ID int CONSTRAINT PK_SomeTable PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (ID)
VALUES(1),(3);
```

Now, let's say we want to insert the following dataset:

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 4 |

If you performed the following query, this will generate the same error you had:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (ID)
SELECT V.ID
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(2),(4))V(ID)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.SomeTable ST
                  WHERE ST.ID = V.ID);
```

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_SomeTable'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SomeTable'. The duplicate key value is (2).

This is because there are *two* rows with the value `2` for `ID` that are trying to be `INSERT`ed. Both rows are trying to be `INSERT`ed because there are no rows in the table with the value `2` at the time the `INSERT` occurs. If you want, you can validate what rows were tried to be `INSERT`ed by commenting out the `INSERT` clause:

```sql
--INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (ID)
SELECT V.ID
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(2),(4))V(ID)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.SomeTable ST
                  WHERE ST.ID = V.ID);
```

| ID |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 4 |

---

For your scenario, one method would be to use a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER` to limit the results to a single row for a single primary key value.

```sql
WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT po.DocNumber,
            po.TenantId,
            po.CreatedById,
            po.OtherField,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY po.DocNumber, po.TenantId ORDER BY <Column(s) to ORDER BY to determine desired row>) AS RN
     FROM dbo.SOURCE_TABLE po
     WHERE po.DeletedById IS NULL
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                       FROM dbo.DESTINATION_TABLE poa
                       WHERE poa.DocNumber = po.DocNumber
                         AND poa.TenantId = po.TenantId))
INSERT INTO dbo.DESTINATION_TABLE (DocNumber,
                                   TenantId,
                                   UserId,
                                   OtherField)
SELECT DocNumber,
       TenantId,
       CreatedById,
       OtherField
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually just came to post that this is the solution I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following query

```
SELECT po.DocNumber, po.TenantId, COUNT(*) as CNT
FROM dbo.SOURCE_TABLE po
GROUP BY po.DocNumber, po.TenantId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

It will show you the rows that are having the issue -- there is more than one of them in the source table.

You then need to figure out what business rule you want to use for the values of items with duplicate rows (x.CreatedById, x.OtherField), maybe you want the first one the max one etc.  Then re-write your select query with a group by to only retrieve one row per key.